# With iptables is it possible to negate multiple IP ranges in a single rule?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I want to log all foreign, not our IP blocks, connections to a port.
For a single range the rule looks like:

```
-A INPUT ! -s 10.20.0.0/16 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -m state --state NEW  -j LOG --log-level 1 --log-prefix "New 8443 Connection"
```

Logically the idea is to not log connections to port `8443` if they are coming from `10.20.0.0/16` or `10.30.0.0/16`. Am I attacking the problem with the wrong logic for iptables? Is this even possible with iptables?

Please note these are just sample IP ranges not the ones I want to stop writing log entries for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ipset:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -m set ! --match-set OUR_IP4 src -j LOG
```

Note that the ipset has to be maintained using a separate tool (including create/restore on boot).

You can use a subchain:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j FOOSERVICE

-N FOOSERVICE
-A FOOSERVICE -s 10.20.0.0/16 -j RETURN
-A FOOSERVICE -s 10.30.0.0/16 -j RETURN
-A FOOSERVICE -j LOG --log-prefix "New connection to foo: "
-A FOOSERVICE -j RETURN
   # optional; subchains always return at the end
```

Comment: The second solution may be clearer to anyone finding the rule in the iptables configuration but I am looking into ipset. It is not clear from the documents I am reading as to whether the sets are permanent, survive a reboot or ephemeral and a script needs to be created to rebuild the set for each boot of the system? If the sets survive a reboot where are they stored?

Comment: Ipsets, much like iptables rules, exist in kernel memory and have to be recreated upon reboot. Check whether your distro provides a service for that (like netfilter-persistent).

Comment: ipset save >/mylocation/mylist  or ipset restore </mylocation/mylist  the -f switch can also be used.

Comment: Then to make the ipset configuration automatic I would have to build a systemd service script that is required by iptables.service, correct? I do not see that any such script is supplied normally. Just want to be sure I am not building something that exists.